# How to use custom error channel and WebFlux.inboundGateway to reply with an error response?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Following the two links below I've created an IntegrationFlow which upon an error, calls into the custom errorFlow. However the behaviour I witness is that the application never replies to the client, it just hangs. How can I reply back to the request from the errorFlow? For reference I've hosted my sample [on github](https://github.com/kevvvvyp/Spring-Integration-Webflux-Demo).

- [How to use custom error channel to produce custom error response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718691/how-to-use-custom-error-channel-to-produce-custom-error-response)
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3276

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(WebFlux.inboundGateway(URI)
                .errorChannel(customErrorChannel()))
                .channel(MessageChannels.flux()) //Work around: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3276
                .transform(p -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error!");
                    //return "Ok Response"; //If we comment the throw and uncomment this, then the the code replies to the request ok.
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public PublishSubscribeChannel customErrorChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("customErrorChannel")
                .transform(p -> {
                    return "Error Response";
                })
                .get();
    }
```

**Request...**

```
GET http://localhost:8080/foo
```

[image: Request screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for sample! Pulling it locally to investigate what is going on...

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm sure I've missed something obvious just not sure what. I'm looking into a global ErrorWebExceptionHandler just now, it might be an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is still a problem with that logic.

We need to investigate it more and figure out the fix.

Meanwhile you could use a workaround for your failing transformer with the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and handle error similar way in the `errorFlow()`. See `returnFailureExpressionResult` as `true`. And your `onFailureExpression`   should be kinda a gateway call to that `customErrorChannel`. Or you can use a `MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive()` API from that expression instead of gateway.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: Thanks for your help,I ended up extending the DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler to handle errors globally (based on the class type of the Spring Integration MessageException root cause). However it would be good to see this fixed.

Comment: The fix is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3319